# How i can create dropdown like this in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app

Hey guys I'm working on some project and need to create a custom dropdown,
like this

[image]

[image]

I am able to make that here is the code, the code is messy but I will refactor it once I make it work. Or if you have some other way how I can accomplish this I'm open to suggestions.

```
  GlobalKey? actionKey = GlobalKey();

 List<String> picked = [];

  List<IconData> icons = [
    Icons.blur_circular_outlined,
    Icons.sports_basketball,
    Icons.sports_baseball_sharp,
    Icons.sports_tennis_rounded,
    Icons.people,
  ];
  List<String> sports = [
    "Fudbal",
    "Kosarka",
    "Tenis",
    "Stoni tenis",
    "Kuglanje"
  ];
  List<int> ints = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

  List<bool> booles = [false, false, false, false, false];
  OverlayEntry? overlayEntry;
  var position;
  double? y;
  double? x;
  void findDropdownData() {
    RenderBox renderBox =
        actionKey!.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    position = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    y = position!.dy;
    x = position!.dx;
  }

  OverlayEntry _overlayEntryBuilder() {
    return OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) {
        return Positioned(
          // top: position,
          left: 16.w,
          right: 16.w,
          child: Material(
            child: dropdownExpanded(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget buildRows(i) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 17.w, vertical: 15.h),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 24.h,
            width: 24.w,
            child: Checkbox(
              activeColor: style.purpleMain,
              value: booles[i],
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  booles[i] = value!;
                  booles[i] == true
                      ? picked.add(sports[i])
                      : picked.remove(sports[i]);
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 10.w,
          ),
          Text(
            sports[i],
            style: TextStyle(
              color: booles[i] == true ? style.purpleMain : Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
          const Spacer(),
          Icon(
            icons[i],
            color: booles[i] == true ? style.purpleMain : Colors.grey,
            size: 15,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget dropdown() {
    return GestureDetector(
      key: actionKey,
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          isPressed = !isPressed;
        });
        if (isPressed == false) {
          overlayEntry = _overlayEntryBuilder();
          Overlay.of(context)!.insert(overlayEntry!);
        }
      },
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 50.h,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: style.e8e8e8),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.w, right: 13.w),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            picked.isEmpty ? pickedEmpty() : pickedNotEmpty(),
            const Spacer(),
            const Icon(
              Icons.arrow_drop_down,
              color: style.bdbdbd,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget pickedEmpty() {
    return Text(
      "Možete obeležiti više aktivnosti",
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 16.sp,
        color: style.bdbdbd,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget pickedNotEmpty() {
    List<Widget> list = <Widget>[];
    for (var i = 0; i < picked.length; i++) {
      list.add(
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.w),
          child: Text(
            picked[i],
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16.sp,
              color: style.bdbdbd,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return Row(children: list);
  }

  Widget dropdownExpanded() {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        border: Border.all(color: style.purpleMain),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                isPressed = !isPressed;
              });
              overlayEntry?.remove();
            },
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 50.h,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.w, right: 13.w),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  picked.isEmpty ? pickedEmpty() : pickedNotEmpty(),
                  const Spacer(),
                  const Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                    color: style.bdbdbd,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const Divider(
            height: 0,
            thickness: 1,
            color: style.e8e8e8,
            indent: 17,
            endIndent: 17,
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              for (int i in ints) buildRows(i),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here are results

[image]

This is what I want to accomplish

[image]

So I just want to move down this expanded dropdown and how to update these booles in the overlay if I don't use overlay it's working as it should but I need to open that dropdown on the top of another content. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

Regarding the UI, it is like an Expansions Tile Widget in flutter. You can implement that dropdown with expansions tile and pass list of items in children,
for `expand`, `collapse` tile after select each item, you can create a global key and control that in UI.

```
final GlobalKey<AppExpansionTileState> expansionTile = new GlobalKey();
```

collapse → `expansionTile.currentState.collapse();`

```
ExpansionTile(
  title: Text(
    "Možete obeležiti više aktivnosti",
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
  ),
  children: <Widget>[
    // put items here
  ],
),
```

*smaple :*

```
Widget customDropDown() => Container(
      // color: Colors.white,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: ListTileTheme(
        dense: true,
        child: ExpansionTile(
          title: const Text(
            "Možete obeležiti više aktivnosti",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
          ),
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(20))),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: const [
                    ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                      title: Text("something"),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                      title: Text("something"),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                      title: Text("something"),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                      title: Text("something"),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: [pageDesign(), customDropDown()],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  fakeWidget(color) => Container(
        height: 100,
        width: double.infinity,
        color: color,
        child: const Center(
          child: Text("widget1"),
        ),
      );

  Widget pageDesign() => Column(
        children: [
          /* you should control this size in diffrent orientation and for big size 
                  device to handle responsive
                  */
          const SizedBox(
            height: 80,
          ),
          fakeWidget(
            Colors.green,
          ),
          fakeWidget(
            Colors.yellow,
          ),
          fakeWidget(
            Colors.orange,
          ),
          fakeWidget(
            Colors.blue,
          ),
        ],
      );
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. How I would overlap content below ExpansionTile and not push it (like DropDown widget)?

Comment: @Milos I added a sample, you can mix this widget with stack to implement UI.

Answer (score 0):

Use [smart_select](https://pub.dev/packages/smart_select) it is fully customizable and you can achieve the design you want easily using this library.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how I would achieve my design with this package?.